# Put dates into a calendar using Javascript and HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

So I (again) am starting web design and decided to try my luck with a very complex website for my father's business. He teaches baseball, and so I'm trying to make a calendar. I finally got it looking exactly how I like using HTML Tables, so now I want to put dates into the calendar but don't want to delete the table since it took so long to perfect.

So the ways I was thinking about doing this was giving a value to all the cells with the first sunday being set to 1 and so on and so forth until I hit 42, but don't know if you could give values to anything other than form fields/objects. I tried using divs and it just got too confusing and impossible for me at my current skill level to get the divs to fall in line how I wanted them to. I plan on having the calendar display openings based off of the admin view of the calendar. I just can't logic my way through it, so how would you guys do it. I want the day values to appear in the proper position, that I can do on my own. I just need the initial month code and then I can go from there.

Here's the JSFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/rccrf/m9kny41m/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div id="JMBody">
<div id="masterBody">
<div id="fixed">
<!--Heading Table-->
    <header id="Title">
    <table id="tTable">
        <tr id="topRow">
            <td id="leftCell"><image id="ball" src="ball.png" /></td>
            <td id="JMB" class="middleCell"><span id="JMBaseball">John Martin Baseball</span><br /><span id="home">Schedule</span></td>
            <td id="rightCell" rowspan="3"><image id="john" src="John4.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="bottomRow">
            <td id="bBat" colspan="2"><img id="bat" src="bat2.png" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </header>
<!--Navigation Bar-->
    <nav id="navBar">
        <table id="navi">
            <tr id="links">
                <td id="link3"><a href="JMHome.html">Home</a></td>
                <td id="link1"><a href="JMProHis.html">Professional<br />History</a></td>
                <td id="link2"><a href="JMPhilosophy.html">Philosophy</a></td>
                <td id="link5"><a href="JMLessons.html">Schedule<br />Lessons</a></td>
                <td id="link6"><a href="JMDirections.html">Driving<br />Directions</a></td>
                <td id="link7"><a href="JMContact.html">Contact Me</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </nav>
</div>
<!--Main Body of the site-->
<div id="mBody">
 <!----------------------------------------------------------------->
 <!----------------Month View 1------------------------------------->
 <!----------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="monthBG" id="monthBG1">
    <table class="monthViewMain1" id="monthView1">
        <tr><!--Month Name Row-->
            <td class="monthName" id="monthName1" colspan=7>November</td>
        </tr>
            <tr><!--Days of the Week Row-->
                <td class="dotw1" id="sun"><b>Sunday</b></td>
                <td class="dotw1" id="mon"><b>Monday</b></td>
                <td class="dotw1" id="tue"><b>Tuesday</b></td>
                <td class="dotw1" id="wed"><b>Wednesday</b></td>
                <td class="dotw1" id="thu"><b>Thursday</b></td>
                <td class="dotw1" id="fri"><b>Friday</b></td>
                <td class="dotw1" id="sat"><b>Saturday</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="weekRow" id="firstWeek1">
                <td class="firstWeekDayCellStart" id="sun1-1" placeholder="1"></td>
                <td class="firstWeekDayCell" id="mon2-1" placeholder="2"></td>
                <td class="firstWeekDayCell" id="tue3-1" placeholder="3"></td>
                <td class="firstWeekDayCell" id="wed4-1" placeholder="4"></td>
                <td class="firstWeekDayCell" id="thu5-1" placeholder="5"></td>
                <td class="firstWeekDayCell" id="fri6-1" placeholder="6"></td>
                <td class="firstWeekDayCellEnd" id="sat7-1" placeholder="7"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="weekRow" id="secondWeek1">
                <td class="weekDayCellStart" id="sun8-1" placeholder="1"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="mon9-1" placeholder="2"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="tue10-1" placeholder="3"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="wed11-1" placeholder="4"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="thu12-1" placeholder="5"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="fri13-1" placeholder="6"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCellEnd" id="sat14-1" placeholder="7"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="weekRow" id="thirdWeek1">
                <td class="weekDayCellStart" id="sun15-1" placeholder="1"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="mon16-1" placeholder="2"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="tue17-1" placeholder="3"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="wed18-1" placeholder="4"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="thu19-1" placeholder="5"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="fri20-1" placeholder="6"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCellEnd" id="sat21-1" placeholder="7"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="weekRow" id="fourthWeek1">
                <td class="weekDayCellStart" id="sun22-1" placeholder="1"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="mon23-1" placeholder="2"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="tue24-1" placeholder="3"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="wed25-1" placeholder="4"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="thu26-1" placeholder="5"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="fri27-1" placeholder="6"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCellEnd" id="sat28-1" placeholder="7"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="weekRow" id="fifthWeek1">
                <td class="weekDayCellStart" id="sun29-1" placeholder="1"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="mon30-1" placeholder="2"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="tue31-1" placeholder="3"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="wed32-1" placeholder="4"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="thu33-1" placeholder="5"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCell" id="fri34-1" placeholder="6"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCellEnd" id="sat35-1" placeholder="7"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="weekRow" id="sixthWeek1">
                <td class="weekDayCellLastSun" id="sun36-1" placeholder="1"></td>
                <td class="lastWeekDayCell" id="mon37-1" placeholder="2"></td>
                <td class="lastWeekDayCell" id="tue38-1" placeholder="3"></td>
                <td class="lastWeekDayCell" id="wed39-1" placeholder="4"></td>
                <td class="lastWeekDayCell" id="thu40-1" placeholder="5"></td>
                <td class="lastWeekDayCell" id="fri41-1" placeholder="6"></td>
                <td class="weekDayCellLastSat" id="sat42-1" placeholder="7"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Footer (also universal) -->
    <footer id="legal">
        <a href="Disclaimer.html" id="aDisclaimer"> <span id="Disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>!!!   </span><span> &copy <b>2014 RCCRF: Function</b> </span>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I highly recommend FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/), possibly used in conjunction with a framework that allows you to do declarative data-binding such as Knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/) or Angular (https://angularjs.org/). Use existing libraries whenever possible and let others do the heavy lifting for you rather than re-invent the wheel. Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful as well. It includes a jQuery plugin and has many options http://javascript.daypilot.org/

There is a free light version that may just do the job: http://javascript.daypilot.org/lite/

Comment: If I change the ids to something like d1...d42 is there a way to use the auto increment feature in javascript to fill in the days using a for loop?